# How to draw image on screen without using Swing?

Tags: java, graphics

I'm trying to display a PNG without a Frame. The idea is to have just a floating image that appears and disappears for 30 seconds. I tried googling this forever but I can't find a solution.

Comment: frame.setUndecorated(true)

Comment: @peeskillet undecorateD :)

Comment: maybe also see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html

Comment: Easily done with Netbeans http://wiki.netbeans.org/Splash_Screen_Beginner_Tutorial

Comment: Or 566,000 [Google hits](https://www.google.com.kh/?gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=FLjGU6j_DJS68gWX4oHQBw#q=splash+screen+in+swing) :-)

Comment: [Just Stackoverflow](https://www.google.com.kh/?gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=FLjGU6j_DJS68gWX4oHQBw#q=site:stackoverflow.com+splash+screen+in+swing)

Comment: @peeskillet I think you're looking for the "Close as duplicate" button...

Comment: @Ordous I didn't really know what the OP wanted. Just making guesses :-)